# Windows Developer License Error 0X80245006

Tags: windows-phone

When trying to create/deploy a Windows Phone 8.1 project using VS Community 2015, I get the following error. What is the reason?

[image: Error 0X80245006: Couldn't get developer license.]

Comment: Does your machine have access to the Internet? Is it behind a proxy / firewall? Do Windows Updates run?

Comment: Hi, I get the same error when using Visual Studio 2013, behind a corporate firewall. I should also mention that I am logged in as an admin on that machine and have an active internet connection. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also not able to figure a way out, is there any log generated that can be viewed? It seems to be a network issue as of now. @npclaudiu Kindly upvote the question.