# Windows SDK installation Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

When I try to install the Windows Phone Template Pack on Visual Studio Community 2015, the following error is obtained.

[image: Exception from HRESULT:0x80070057]

What is the reason? Where can I check the error log from?

Comment: I know it's been a bit, but can you tell me from where you are installing the Windows Phone Template Pack?

Comment: There is an option in Visual Studio to get project templates online, I select the corresponding option there. In addition, I also installed the offline installer for the windows phone SDK available from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8442

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1. The Windows SDK link you provided (http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8442) is for Windows 7. It is not compatible with Visual Studio 2015 for Windows Phone development.
2. I think this error you're seeing with the Windows Phone Template Pack (HRESULT: 0x80070057) is because the Windows and Windows Phone 8.1 Tools are not installed on your computer along with Visual Studio Community 2015.

I am able to reproduce this only when the Windows and Windows Phone 8.1 Tools are not installed.

[image: error dialog]

If I click **skip**, then I see the error dialog you included above.

To resolve this issue,

- Go into the Control Panel
- Open up Add/Remove Programs (or Programs & Features depending on your OS version)
- Select Visual Studio Community 2015, then click Change
- In VS setup, click Modify
- Make sure that the "Tools and Windows SDKs" feature under "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools" is checked.

If you're running Windows 8.0/8.1/10 x64 Professional or higher with a Hyper-V capable computer and then you should also be able to install the Windows Phone 8.1 emulators.

[image]

-Paul Chapman [MSFT]

Comment: thanks, could you also possibly help me with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583568/windows-developer-license-error-0x80245006)

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer today, but it no longer works, or doesn't work if the host OS is Windows 7 Pro.  I just installed Windows 7 Pro (plus all updates) and then VS2015 (plus all of ITS updates) on an otherwise CLEAN computer.  NO SDK was installed.  My options for modify look like this:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Mofiy Options]

The Windows 8.1...Tools option is TOTALLY MISSING.  The Windows 10.0 SDK is offered under the Universal Windows...Tools option, but that doesn't help me with Windows 7 targeted development.

Also, FWIW, the Windows 8.1 install tool that Microsoft is offering for download just gets an APPCRASH every time I try to use it (and yes, I've downloaded it several times, even to different machines, but always with the same result.)

So for me, I can either stick with Visual Studio 2010 or suffer the user interface abomination that is/was Visual Studio 2012 (not gonna happen).  Sigh.