# Dependency error with Darkflow installation

Tags: python, visual-studio, anaconda, yolo, darkflow

I am trying to install darkflow using Anaconda Prompt. I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. However, when I type

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

It displays the following message:

```
running build_ext
building 'darkflow.cython_utils.nms' extension
error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'
```

I installed the corresponding Visual Studio SDK from: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015
However, it keeps displaying the same error and it appears that the file "Platform SDK" is still not installed, any idea how to fix that?

Cheers!

Comment: Found similar question here, but I haven't weeded through all the comments to resolve it for me either...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: found I did not have the SDK option selected in Visual Studio.  Here is a link that helped...still testing:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691318/windows-sdk-installation-visual-studio-community-2015